# difference between source and fields

Tags: elasticsearch

Whats the differenet between [source](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html) and [fields](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-fields.html)
acording to documentation they booth are used to listing fields which we want to from index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields is best used for fields that are stored. When not stored it behaves similar to source.

So in case all the fields you want in result are all stored it would be faster filtering using "fields" instead of source.

Also fields can be used to get [metadata fields](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-fields.html) if they are stored.

However one of the limitations of fields is that it can be used only to fetch leaf fields i.e it cannot be used on nested fields/object.

The following article in [found](https://www.found.no/foundation/elasticsearch-fields/) provides a good explanation.